# OpenStreetMap create Network Dataset Error: Error Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040353

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, openstreetmap, network-dataset

I am trying to use the OSM Toolbox in ArcMap 10.8.1 to create a network dataset from downloaded OpenStreetMap Data. Here is the methodology I used.

1. Downloaded us-south-latest.osm from geofabrik
2. Load OSM File tool in OpenStreetMap toolbox with all the necessary fields (Tags) for a Network Dataset, and loaded data into a File Geodatabase
3. Used Create OSM Network Dataset tool, with the DriveGeneric.xml configuration file.

I have been receiving this error and cannot figure out what the issue is. I have tried both the 32 Bit and 64 bit OSM Editor Extension, for ArcMap and received the same exact error. I have also tried the tool on 2 machines.

```
Executing: OSMGPCreateNetworkDataset C:\Users\morij\Dropbox\OpenStreetMap\OSMNetwork.gdb\OSMNetworkSouth "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\ND_ConfigFiles\DriveGeneric.xml" C:\Users\morij\Dropbox\OpenStreetMap\OSMNetwork.gdb\OSMNetworkSouth\OSMNetworkSouth_nd
Start Time: Fri May 28 19:26:33 2021

Extracting Edge Features

Select_analysis



Extracting Junction Features

Select_analysis



Assigning Network Connectivity Groups


Extracting Turn Restrictions

Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040353
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDatasetContainer2.CreateDataset(IDEDataset DataElement)

   at ESRI.ArcGIS.OSM.GeoProcessing.NetworkDataset.CreateTempNDS()

   at ESRI.ArcGIS.OSM.GeoProcessing.NetworkDataset.ExtractTurnRestrictions()

   at ESRI.ArcGIS.OSM.GeoProcessing.RunTaskManager.ExecuteTask(String messageName, Action task)

   at ESRI.ArcGIS.OSM.GeoProcessing.NetworkDataset.CreateNetworkDataset()

   at ESRI.ArcGIS.OSM.GeoProcessing.OSMGPCreateNetworkDataset.Execute(IArray paramvalues, ITrackCancel TrackCancel, IGPEnvironmentManager envMgr, IGPMessages message)
Failed to execute (OSMGPCreateNetworkDataset).
Failed at Fri May 28 21:16:59 2021 (Elapsed Time: 1 hours 50 minutes 25 seconds)
```